# ExtJS selecting certain cell from a row

Tags: dom, extjs, extjs4

I have a handler : onCalendarEditFunc that is ment to edit selected cell from the grid. For now I have this:

```
onCalendarEditFunc: function() {
        var selection = this.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        requires : [
            'Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing',
            'Ext.grid.column.Column'
        ]



        edit = this.editing;
        console.log(this.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection());
        edit.cancelEdit();
    //  this.store.insert(0, rec);
        edit.startEditByPosition({
            row: this.store.indexOf(selection[0]),
            column: 0
        });

    },
```

where `row: this.store.indexOf(selection[0]),` works fine and being like that I can edit the first cell from a selected row. But my row has a multiple columns, so I want to give `column:` a value which is the value of the selected cell.

Thanks

Leron

Comment: Do you know column index you want to start your editor on?

Comment: No the idea is that I have a grid with say - 5 columns and in this grid i generate rows based on an SQL query. I say this just to know that the number of rows is not static.So when a user want to change some info on column3 row15 he jsut click the cell, but the the function startEditByPosition take two options the first one - the row I manage to get dynamicly by I want to intercept the column elected for editin by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to detect the exact cell selected by the user (if you want to edit button functionality which make the selected cell editable as it was in my case) here is what you can do. That's the begining of the initComponent function

```
initComponent: function(){

        this.editing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing');
        Ext.apply(this, {
            title: 'Календар',
            frame: false,
            plugins : [this.editing],
            store: 'CalendarEvents',
            selModel: {
                selType: 'cellmodel'
            },
```

The important part here is

```
selModel: {
          selType: 'cellmodel'
          },
```

which then allows you to use the following syntaxis in the edit function:

```
editfunction: function() {
    var selection = this.view.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition();
    requires : [
        'Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing',
        'Ext.grid.column.Column',
        'Ext.selection.CellModel'
    ]



    edit = this.editing;
    //console.log(this.view.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition().column);

    edit.cancelEdit();
//  this.store.insert(0, rec);
    edit.startEditByPosition({
        row: selection.row,
        column: selection.column
    });

},
```

And this is it, now you get the position of the selected cell and pass it so you can start editing from there or as it is in the function:

```
edit.startEditByPosition({
            row: selection.row,
            column: selection.column
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
edit.cancelEdit();
edit.startEdit(selection[0] /* this basically your record */, column /* 3 for example */);
```

Comment: Yeah, but instead hardcoding '3' it must be a variable with a value the selected column from the row. Anyway I found a workaraound solution so I'm gonna post it here.

Comment: I put variable there - you can calculate it.